# Place every sentence from a text file into an array but detect headers/titles

Tags: c#, arrays, regex, string, replace

I need to get each sentence from a text document/string into an array.

The issue is with how to handle headers, titles etc. sections of text which are not part of a sentence, but don't end in a full stop ". " to detect. 
Being unable to detect these will result them being stuck on to the front of the following sentence (if I use ". " to distinguish sentences) which I can't have happen.

Initially I was going to use:

```
contentRefined = content.Replace(" \n", ". ");
```

Which I thought would remove all of the empty lines and newlines, as well as place full stops on the ends of headers to be detected and treated as sentences, it would result in ". . " but I could again Replace them with nothing.

But didn't work it simply left the full empty lines and just put a ". " at the start of the empty line.... As well as ". " at the start of every paragraph

I have now tried:

```
contentRefined = Regex.Replace(content, @"^\s+$[\r\n]*", "", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

Which fully removes the full empty lines, but doesn't get me closer to adding a full stop to the ends of the headers.

I need to place the sentences and headers/titles in an array, I'm not sure if there is a method of which I can do this without having to split the string by something such as ". "

Edit: Full current code showing how I get the test from the file

```
 public void sentenceSplit()
    {
        content = File.ReadAllText(@"I:\Project\TLDR\Test Text.txt");
        contentRefined = Regex.Replace(content, @"^\s+$[\r\n]*", "", RegexOptions.Multiline);
        //contentRefined = content.Replace("\n", ". ");
    }
```

Comment: Will you post a short sample of the text document you're parsing (including sentence, headers, and titles)?

Comment: Also, how are you reading the file? That may be the time to filter out the headings if you don't need them.

Comment: I was vague on the specific document as I need this to be able to handle most documents. The document I'm currently testing it on is a basic .txt file, I just did some examples of whats happening here: http://pastebin.com/3rc4i5wT

Comment: @RufusL I'm currently using File.ReadAllText I've updated my question to show this, I am currently testing out your answer suggestion though :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm making an assumption that 'Header' and 'Title' are on their own line and do not end in a period.

If that's the case, then this may work for you:

```
var filePath = @"C:\Temp\temp.txt";
var sentences = new List<string>();

using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
{
    while (reader.Peek() >= 0)
    {
        var line = reader.ReadLine();

        if (line.Trim().EndsWith("."))
        {
            line.Split(new[] {'.'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                .ToList()
                .ForEach(l => sentences.Add(l.Trim() + "."));
        }
    }
}

// Output sentences to console
sentences.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

**UPDATE**

Another approach using the `File.ReadAllLines()` method, and displaying the sentences in a `RichTextBox`:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var filePath = @"C:\Temp\temp.txt";

    var sentences = File.ReadAllLines(filePath)
        // Only select lines that end in a period
        .Where(l => l.Trim().EndsWith("."))
        // Split each line into sentences (one line may have many sentences)
        .SelectMany(s => s.Split(new[] {'.'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        // Trim any whitespace off the ends of the sentence and add a period to the end
        .Select(s => s.Trim() + ".")
        // And finally cast it to a List (or you could do 'ToArray()')
        .ToList();

    // To show each sentence in the list on it's own line in the rtb:
    richTextBox1.Text = string.Join("\n", sentences);

    // Or to show them all, one after another:
    richTextBox1.Text = string.Join(" ", sentences);
}
```

**UPDATE**

Now that I think I understand what you're asking, here's what I would do. First, I would create some classes to manage all this stuff. If you break the document down into parts, you get something like:

> HEADER
>
> Paragraph sentence one. Paragraph sentence two. Paragraph
>   sentence three with a number, like in this quote: "$5.00 doesn't go as
>   far as it used to".
>
> Header Over an Empty Section
>
> Header over multiple paragraphs
>
> Paragraph sentence one. Paragraph
>   sentence two. Paragraph sentence three with a number, like in this
>   quote: "$5.00 doesn't go as far as it used to".
>
> Paragraph sentence one. Paragraph sentence two. Paragraph sentence
>   three with a number, like in this quote: "$5.00 doesn't go as far as
>   it used to".
>
> Paragraph sentence one. Paragraph sentence two. Paragraph sentence
>   three with a number, like in this quote: "$5.00 doesn't go as far as
>   it used to".

So I would create the following classes. First, one to represent a 'Section'. This is defined by a Header and zero to many paragraphs:

```
private class Section
{
    public string Header { get; set; }

    public List<Paragraph> Paragraphs { get; set; }

    public Section()
    {
        Paragraphs = new List<Paragraph>();
    }
}
```

Then I would define a Paragraph, which contains one or more sentences:

```
private class Paragraph
{
    public List<string> Sentences { get; set; }

    public Paragraph()
    {
        Sentences = new List<string>();
    }
}
```

Now I can populate a List of Sections to represent the document:

```
var filePath = @"C:\Temp\temp.txt";

var sections = new List<Section>();
var currentSection = new Section();
var currentParagraph = new Paragraph();

using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
{
    while (reader.Peek() >= 0)
    {
        var line = reader.ReadLine().Trim();

        // Ignore blank lines
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line)) continue;

        if (line.EndsWith("."))
        {
            // This line is a paragraph, so add all the sentences
            // it contains to the current paragraph
            line.Split(new[] {". "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                .Select(l => l.Trim().EndsWith(".") ? l.Trim() : l.Trim() + ".")
                .ToList()
                .ForEach(l => currentParagraph.Sentences.Add(l));

            // Now add this paragraph to the current section
            currentSection.Paragraphs.Add(currentParagraph);

            // And set it to a new paragraph for the next loop
            currentParagraph = new Paragraph();
        }
        else if (line.Length > 0)
        {
            // This line is a header, so we're starting a new section.
            // Add the current section to our list and create a 
            // a new one, setting this line as the header.
            sections.Add(currentSection);
            currentSection = new Section {Header = line};
        }
    }

    // Finally, if the current section contains any data, add it to the list
    if (currentSection.Header.Length > 0 || currentSection.Paragraphs.Any())
    {
        sections.Add(currentSection);
    }
}
```

Now we have the whole document in a list of sections, and we know the order, the headers, the paragraphs, and the sentences they contain. As an example of how you can analyze it, here's a way to write it back out to a `RichTextBox`:

```
// We can build the document section by section
var documentText = new StringBuilder();

foreach (var section in sections)
{
    // Here we can display headers and paragraphs in a custom way.
    // For example, we can separate all sections with a blank line:
    documentText.AppendLine();

    // If there is a header, we can underline it
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(section.Header))
    {
        documentText.AppendLine(section.Header);
        documentText.AppendLine(new string('-', section.Header.Length));
    }

    // We can mark each paragraph with an arrow (--> )
    foreach (var paragraph in section.Paragraphs)
    {
        documentText.Append("--> ");

        // And write out each sentence, separated by a space
        documentText.AppendLine(string.Join(" ", paragraph.Sentences));
    }
}

// To make the underline approach above look
// half-way decent, we need a fixed-width font
richTextBox1.Font = new Font(FontFamily.GenericMonospace, 9);

// Now set the RichTextBox Text equal to the StringBuilder Text
richTextBox1.Text = documentText.ToString();
```

Comment: I'm doing this as a WinForm and I'm feeling extremely dumb as I don't know how to display the entire contents of the array into the rich textbox I have to see if its worked correctly.

Comment: Do you want each sentence on it's own line, or just one after the other?

Comment: Ah this is great, apart from it removes the headers so lines that don't end in ".", Is there a way to store the headers somewhere? Also its splitting by every "." so values like 52.000 are split, it doesn't allow me to add a space to what it splits by.

Comment: I see. Your example did not have values like that, and your example also has a bunch of sentences in the beginning that don't have a space separating them. But yes, it would be easy to do; just split on ". " (period space). As far as saving headers, that is not too hard either. You can do it as you read through the file (in the first example) by adding an 'else' clause.

Comment: I thought you WANTED to remove the headers? What exactly do you want in the end?

Comment: an array which contains the sentences and the headers all as separate entries, in the end I'll need to also know which sentences were in a paragraph together and due to the "\n" newlines or w/e the headers/titles/paragraphs will standout. I need this as I have to do analysis on the words within each sentence then their paragraph and so on I know this all might sound weird.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: That is not what you specified in your question...can this be answered and you ask a new one?

Comment: "The issue is with how to handle headers, titles etc. sections of text which are not part of a sentence, but don't end in a full stop ". " to detect."..... "as well as place full stops on the ends of headers to be detected and treated as sentences"...... "doesn't get me closer to adding a full stop to the ends of the headers."... I say throughout that I need to detect the headers so they can be treated as sentences and not attached to the following sentence through adding a full stop, or if there is another way to directly detect.

Comment: Ah, I see. I guess I just interpreted it differently! I've added a more complex, but ultimately easier, way to do this using custom classes instead of an array.